# Soap request working in SoapUI but not in Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, soap, soapui, soap-client

I've been searching around for a solution to my problem, but to no avail. I'm trying to send a soap request through a Wordpress plugin using the following:

```
function soapRequest($soapUsername, $soapNonce, $soapDateTime, $soapPassword) {

$wsdl = 'http://www.beautyfort.com/api/wsdl/v2/wsdl.wsdl';
$trace = true;
$exceptions = false;

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => $trace, 'exceptions' => $exceptions));

// Must be a stdClass (and not an array)
$auth = new stdClass();
$auth->Username = $soapUsername;
$auth->Nonce = $soapNonce;
$auth->Created = $soapDateTime;
$auth->Password = $soapPassword;

$header = new SoapHeader('http://www.beautyfort.com/api/', 'AuthHeader', $auth);

$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$xml_array['TestMode'] = 'true';
$xml_array['StockFileFormat'] = 'JSON';
$xml_array['SortBy'] = 'StockCode';

try {
    $response = $client->GetStockFile($xml_array);
}

catch (Exception $e) {
    log_me("Error!");
    log_me($e -> getMessage());
    log_me('Last response: '. $client->__getLastResponse());
}

log_me('Last request: '. $client->__getLastRequest());
log_me($response);
}
```

This produces the following request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.beautyfort.com/api/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns1:AuthHeader>
            <ns1:Username>joetest</ns1:Username>
            <ns1:Nonce>htflFfIKM4</ns1:Nonce>
            <ns1:Created>2019-02-09T10:13:51.000Z</ns1:Created>
            <ns1:Password>NGFjYTJiNzJmOWY2MzBmY2M2MjJkNjg1MDgyMWRjMzQxOGY1YTNjYQ==</ns1:Password>
        </ns1:AuthHeader>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:GetStockFileRequest>
            <ns1:TestMode>true</ns1:TestMode>
            <ns1:StockFileFormat>JSON</ns1:StockFileFormat>
            <ns1:SortBy>StockCode</ns1:SortBy>
        </ns1:GetStockFileRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And I get an invalid credentials error. I've also been testing in SoupUI and the following request works:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:api="http://www.beautyfort.com/api/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <api:AuthHeader>
            <api:Username>joetest</api:Username>
            <api:Nonce>tJrsRlQt6i</api:Nonce>
            <api:Created>2019-02-06T23:34:11.000Z</api:Created>
            <api:Password>ZTBhMmE5OGY4YTNlZWIzZTE0ZTc2ZjZiZDBhM2RhMjJmNzAxNzYwZA==</api:Password>
        </api:AuthHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <api:GetStockFileRequest>
            <api:TestMode>true</api:TestMode>
            <api:StockFileFormat>JSON</api:StockFileFormat>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <api:FieldDelimiter>,</api:FieldDelimiter>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <api:StockFileFields>
                <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
                <api:StockFileField>StockCode</api:StockFileField>
                <api:StockFileField>Category</api:StockFileField>
                <api:StockFileField>Brand</api:StockFileField>
                <api:StockFileField>Collection</api:StockFileField>
                <api:StockFileField>Category</api:StockFileField>
            </api:StockFileFields>
            <api:SortBy>StockCode</api:SortBy>
        </api:GetStockFileRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now the only differences I can see (apart from the optional fields) is the names of the namespace, and the use of the Xml tag at the top of the request. Both of these shouldn't matter right? I'd really appreciate your help on this as I've been scratching my head for ages.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The given credentials differ between your xml from the soap client and your xml you use in soapui. Perhaps the credentials are really not valid?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The same bit of code is producing the credentials for both. Unfortunately the api requires the credentials to be different for every request, so I cannot test the exact same credentials in SoupUI and my Wordpress plugin.

Comment: Hello ,
i'm also this issue, for me its working with sandbox but  not working with the production credentials , please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Your perfect just need to set UTC timezone and secret format like below:

```
base64 encoded(sha1(Nonce . Created . Secret))
```